# F grade during exchange semester

Tags: graduate-admissions, europe, economics

I am a European guy and will apply for the Masters in Economics next year. I did an exchange semester in Germanys top school and basically due to too much partying I got an F at one of the related class. The thing is that my GPA is relatively good. 3.6/4 and all my other grades are above B+ in related courses so I dont have any B or C except for this F. But it is impossible for me to retake this course. How is this going to be approached by the admission commities? I can even say that I passed other hard and similar classes of mine both in my exchange and home semesters. I failed an Time Series Econometrics class.

Comment: Thank you so much. Me experiencing this problem in my exchange semester , does it put me in a more reasonable position at least? And not retaking the exact class but taking and succesfully passing other super related classes?

Comment: Time series econometrics is very difficult to take in general.  If you show particularly good math grades you can point to these as evidence that you can succeed otherwise.

Comment: I have 2 statistics classes that I passed succesfully. One intro to econometrics class and one another Forecasting Econometrics class that I passed in my exchange semester. So I think it can compensate. But still I guess my chances will decrease a lot.

Comment: Be honest, state that you took a bad grade because excessive partying. In Germany. Everyone will think it is a joke, so you are not lieing, at least.

Comment: Why would think that it is a joke?